# Divide the results of two select queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, divide

I have two SQL count queries that on their own work fine, they are:

```
SELECT count(*) AS TOTAL_PROGRESS_BY_LINE_
FROM dbo.PID_Components_PROCESS_LINES
WHERE ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'C'

RESULT: TOTAL_PROGRESS_BY_LINE_ = 26

SELECT count(*) AS TOTAL_LINES_BY_PROJECT_
FROM dbo.PID_Components_PROCESS_LINES
WHERE PROJECT_NUMBER_ = 'PJ001234'

RESULT: TOTAL_LINES_BY_PROJECT_ = 130
```

Now how to do I add to the query to get the percentage of 26/130??

I have a new query to go along with how to get percentages.

Here it is:

```
SELECT ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_, PROJECT_NUMBER_,
CASE
    WHEN ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'A' THEN 'NOT IN MODEL'
    WHEN ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'B' THEN 'ROUGHED IN'
    WHEN ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'C' THEN 'PARTIAL CHECK'
    WHEN ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'D' THEN 'READY FOR FINAL CHECK'
    WHEN ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'E' THEN '100% COMPLETE'
    WHEN ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = '0' THEN 'ISSUE FOR CONSTRUCTION'
END AS PROGRESS_PER_LINE_
FROM PID_Components_PROCESS_LINES
WHERE PROJECT_NUMBER_ = 'PJ001234'
ORDER BY ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_
```

this brings back results below:

```
ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_   PROJECT_NUMBER_ PROGRESS_PER_LINE_
A                       PJ001234        NOT IN MODEL
B                       PJ001234        ROUGHED IN
C                       PJ001234        PARTIAL CHECK
D                       PJ001234        READY FOR FINAL CHECK
```

If I remove the `Distinct` from my query there are obviously multiple rows for each level of progress.  How do I add to the above distinct query to have a column at the end with the rate or percent of each level of progress compared to the overall number of lines?

Comment: The values you are dividing are integers. Do you want an integer result, i.e. `0`, the percentage as an integer, i.e. `20`, or something else (`0.2000`, `20.00`, `'Not much.'`)?

Comment: I would like  the result to be 20.00. I apologize I'm new to what I consider "more advanced" queries.

Comment: The columns I'm doing the count on are varchar data type if that makes a difference?

Comment: Please put new questions in <drumroll> _new questions_. The title, comments and answers won't make any sense if you change the initial question and it's all quite confusing if you try to wedge another question into the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation and simple division in one query:

```
select
  100.0 *
  count(
    case when ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'C'
    then 1
    end
  )
  /
  nullif(count(
    case when PROJECT_NUMBER_ = 'PJ001234'
    then 1
    end
  ), 0) as rate_
FROM dbo.PID_Components_PROCESS_LINES
WHERE ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'C'
  or PROJECT_NUMBER_ = 'PJ001234'
```

Comment: This also came back as 0 for rate.  The columns I'm doing the count on are varchar data type if that makes a difference?

Comment: @Drafter-SQL I've updated the code with implicit conversion to decimal and your desired scale to 100

Comment: That did the trick, the result came back as 20.000. I appreciate all the help and apologize for not providing some sample data.  I have a follow up question and will put together some sample data to provide with the question this time.

Comment: @Drafter-SQL You're welcome. If you think some answer fits well with your needs and provides good enough solution you may [accept it or upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to indicate it as useful.

Answer (score 2):

Select them as a subquery.

By default the result will be an integer because `count(*)` returns an `int`. For a `decimal` result convert to a `decimal`.

```
SELECT (
    SELECT CONVERT(decimal(9,2),COUNT(*)) AS TOTAL_PROGRESS_BY_LINE_
    FROM dbo.PID_Components_PROCESS_LINES
    WHERE ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'C'
) / (
    SELECT CONVERT(decimal(9,2),COUNT(*)) AS TOTAL_LINES_BY_PROJECT_
    FROM dbo.PID_Components_PROCESS_LINES
    WHERE PROJECT_NUMBER_ = 'PJ001234'
)
```

Comment: @Drafter-SQL thats because when you divide an int by an int in SQL Server the result is always an int. So convert to decimal as I have shown. If you had shown your desired results in your question this would have been addressed.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @firstone INT;
DECLARE @secondone INT;
SELECT @firstone = count(*)
FROM dbo.PID_Components_PROCESS_LINES
WHERE ISOGEN_LINE_PROGRESS_ = 'C';

SELECT @secondone = count(*)
FROM dbo.PID_Components_PROCESS_LINES
WHERE PROJECT_NUMBER_ = 'PJ001234';

SELECT @firstone / @secondone AS resultthing

SELECT @firstone /CAST(@secondone AS DECIMAL (9,2))
```

Comment: I appreciate the fast responses but that returns 0???

Comment: You may have to CAST the result but that was not specified

Answer (score 0):

You could use a common table expression to get the counts and then `select` the desired results in one *swell foop*:

```
with Counts as (
  select
    ( select Count(*) from Sys.Tables ) as NumberOfTables,
    ( select Count(*) from Sys.Columns ) as NumberOfColumns
  )
  select NumberOfTables, NumberOfColumns,
    NumberOfColumns / NumberOfTables as ColumnsPerTable,
    ( 100 * NumberOfColumns ) / NumberOfTables as IntegerPercentColumnsPerTable,
    ( 100.0 * NumberOfColumns ) / NumberOfTables as NumericPercentColumnsPerTable
    from Counts;
```

I used existing tables since you chose not to supply DDL and sample data. So it goes.